# Why is the horizontal plane field of $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}$ integrable?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

In Peter Scott's "The geometry of 3-manifolds" he shows that $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$ is distinct from  $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}$ by showing that the horizontal plane field induced from $T\mathbb{H}^2$ is non integrable for $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$ but the horizontal plane field is integrable for $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}$. I'm wondering how I can show that this is the case.

I understand his argument for $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$ but I dont see why it is integrable for $\mathbb{H}^2\times \mathbb{R}$. He defines horizontalI by:  Let $x\in\mathbb{H}^2$, and $v\in\mathbb T_x\mathbb{H}^2$ and consider all of the geodesic paths through $x$ and lift them to horizontal paths (paths which transport any tangent vector parallel) in $T\mathbb{H}^2$ through $v$ this collection forms a surface in $T\mathbb{H}^2$. The tangent plane to this surface at $v$ is called horizontal. To obtain a plane field on $T\mathbb{H}^2$ we can consider all such tangent planes at every point in $T\mathbb{H}^2$.

This is horizontal plane field that then can be induced onto  $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$. Is there a more intuitive way to define it for $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}$? If not how can I see that this same horizontal plane field is integrable for $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What have you tried? Certainly the claim for $\Bbb H^2\times\Bbb R$ is evident. How precisely is the horizontal subspace defined in $\widetilde{SL(2,\Bbb R)}$? Scott must give more details than you have.

Comment: I understand his argument for $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$ but I dont see why it is integrable for $\mathbb{H}^2\times \mathbb{R}$. He defines horizontal

Comment: Well, with no further context, I would assume the horizontal subspace at $(x,t)$ in $\Bbb H^2\times\Bbb R$ is $t=\text{constant}$.

Comment: Sorry my comment was added before I finished it - I added more details to the question.

Comment: For each $t \in \mathbb R$, the horizontal vector field at each point of $\mathbb H^2 \times \{t\}$ is, well, horizontal, meaning that it is tangent to $\mathbb H^2 \times \{t\}$. And so there, staring at you, is a surface which is tangent to the horizontal vector field at each point of $\mathbb H^2 \times \{t\}$, namely.... $\mathbb H^2 \times \{t\}$ itself.